# Exclude a product category from custom displayed button on Woocommerce archives

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I'm using the following code to add a "Back to All Categories" link on product category pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'wc_add_content_on_category_pages', 30 );
function wc_add_content_on_category_pages() {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        echo '<a class="button categories-link" href="http://brossiebellecom.ipage.com/new/rentals/">Back to All Categories</a>';
    }
}
```

However, I need to exclude the "Retail" category only from displaying the "Back to All Categories" link.

How can I get the current product category name?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec That worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the following to exclude "Retail" product category *(**Note:** It's **an action hook** but not a filter hook)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'wc_add_content_on_category_pages', 30 );
function wc_add_content_on_category_pages() {
    if ( ! is_product_category() ) return; // Only product category archives pages

    if ( get_queried_object()->name == "Retail" ) return; // Exclude "Retail" product category 

    // Output "Back to All Categories" custom button
    echo '<a class="button categories-link" href="http://brossiebellecom.ipage.com/new/rentals/">Back to All Categories</a>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works